# iOS app to transfer data from external hardware to iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, hardware, data-transfer

I am developing an application in swift in which i want to transfer some data from my hardware device(A kind of chip) to iPhone.Some data will be displayed on the screen.But i want to use the standard lightning cable.Is it possible?

Comment: You should have tried "something" prior to posting here.  You can find general information for the question you posted on Google.    Then you will have a dev environment setup, a language chosen, and you can get help here.

Comment: I have tried searching prior to posting.I am developing the app in swift.But what i am concerned with is if i can use the standard lightning cable or do i need some other cable like Redpark cable?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of communication isn´t possible using a lightning cable but with a lightning connector. You need to include a chip in your hardware for the authentication. 
You must apply to become a Mfi (Made for iPhone) certified developer. Also you have to submit your hardware to Apple so they can review your app together with the hardware device.

Some useful links are:

- [Apples SDK for this kind of communication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory)
- [Made for iPhone Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: My hardware device needs to be MFI certified?

Comment: Yes. You need a special chip on your hardware for the communication over Lightning (you need this also for Bluetooth 2).

Comment: I want to connect that hardware through a cable not with bluetooth.Redpark cable is available for the same but the speed is 140 kbps and i need around 450 kbps.Is it even possible to go with standard lightning cable?

Comment: As i mentioned above you need a special authentication chip to communicate with external hardware over lightning. It does not matter if it is a cable or a connector on your hardware. Please see the FAQ from Apple: https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action